# Using DS.FixtureAdapter and DS.RESTAdapter at the same time

Tags: ember.js

I would like to use both adapters, depending on the route. Currently I have the following store:

```
if (window.USE_FIXTURES) { var my_adapter = 'DS.FixtureAdapter'; }
else                     { var my_adapter = SettingsApp.Adapter.create(); }

SettingsApp.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter:  my_adapter
});
```

(`SettinsApp.Adapter` is a `DS.RESTAdapter`)

But what I would like is to have two stores. Is it possible to do this, on a route-by-route basis? Could somebody provide an example on how to configure the router for this?

Answer (score 6):

> But what I would like is to have two stores. Is it possible to do this, on a route-by-route basis?

As per design you should never want to have multiple stores in your App. But instead the possibility to have an adapter on a **per model basis** exists.

This would look something like this:

```
DS.Store.registerAdapter('App.LegacyModel', App.MyLegacyAdapter.extend({});
```

If you have multiple models that use the same adapter you could do:

```
DS.Store.registerAdapter(['App.FooModel', 'App.BarModel'], App.MyAdapter.extend({});
```

The store will then use the model type corresponding adapter when making requests.

You can still specify a *default adapter* for the store by using the this syntax:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'DS.RESTAdapter'
});
```

This default adapter will be used as a fallback if you try to load a record that does not have an adapter specified for its type.

> Is it possible to do this, on a route-by-route basis?

Following best practices, if you want to use a different model other than the one looked up by convention (e.g. using your route's name) you could do something like:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', App.MySpecialModel.find());
  }
});
```

Also worth mentioning is that the `DS.FixtureAdapter` does not replace nor have the same feature set as the `DS.RESTAdapter`, it's only meant to provide simple mockup data for your app, so switching between adapter's would not work in case of the `DS.FixtureAdapter` & `DS.RESTAdapter`. Use `DS.FixtureAdapter` when you don't yet care to communicate with a backend, but will store your data as "fixtures" in the client.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've actually done this as described: built an app with some models (defined in code and not editable by users) stored in DS.FixtureAdapter, and others (created and mutable in-app and stored in a back-end) using DS.RESTAdapter.

Comment: Not yet working for me: doing `DS.Store.RegisterAdapter('App.MyModel', 'DS.fixtureAdapter');` causes an exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Object ... has no method 'RegisterAdapter'`

Comment: it's `registerAdapter` not `RegisterAdapter` and `DS.FixtureAdapter` and not `DS.fixtureAdapter` :)

Comment: yes thanks, I just found that in the ember-data codebase too. It was not easy to make those two mistakes in a single line of code :)

Comment: But strangely enough, even after specifying the `FixtureAdapter` it is still using the `RESTAdapter` for the model ...

Comment: have you tried defining the adapter not as a string but like a class e.g. `DS.Store.registerAdapter('App.MyModel', DS.FixtureAdapter);`?

Comment: Yep, tried everything, but the store is just using the RESTAdapter. I'll try to reproduce this with a jsfiddle-

Comment: registerAdapter is no longer available in Ember.js. I've posted an updated solution.

Answer (score 5):

@intuitivepixel's answer no longer works in current day Ember (v1.0+); as registerAdapter no longer exists in the API.

Nowadays you can just declare an Adapter for each model where you want to override the adapter choice:

```
App.LegacyModel = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.LegacyAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0):

@gonvaled it might be because you used

```
DS.Store.registerAdapter('App.LegacyModel', App.MyLegacyAdapter.extend({});
```

and not

```
App.Store.registerAdapter('App.LegacyModel', App.MyLegacyAdapter.extend({});
```

I add the same problem and by using App.Sotre it was all fixed.

For my use case i needed 2 different adapters for the same model. To save all my products viewed from the rest adapter to be visible offline on an history page using the fixture adapter and sql lite.

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 13,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        url: app.apiUrl,
        namespace: app.apiNamespace
    })
});


App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
});

App.Producthistory = App.Product;

App.Store.registerAdapter('App.Producthistory', DS.FixtureAdapter);

App.HistoriqueRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', App.Producthistory.find());
    }
});
```