# Simple session data in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm not sure how to store simple session data in an Ember.js application. As a toy project, I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe game, and I would like to store the player's nickname. In plain javascript, I'd store it in a cookie, but I guess it's not very "emberic".

Any tip about the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist state you have various options. With ember-data this is straightforward, you just change the adapter on your store.

For example to use `LocalStorage` apis to store models you can use,

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 12,
  adapter: DS.LSAdapter.create()
});
```

Now if you have a Player model in your app, when you save a record it will get automatically get saved in the `LocalStorage`.

The [LSAdapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) is a small library that adds this support.

Alternatively if aren't using ember-data you can directly persist to local storage on save and then load it in your `model()` hook on a Route. For simple key-value stuff I recommend using a library like [lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/).

Comment: I'm using ember-data, so it's ok. But I'm already using DS.FixtureAdapter as the Store adapter. Is it possible to use different adapters to handle different kinds of data?

Comment: Yes, you can use different adapters for different models. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268899/using-ds-fixtureadapter-and-ds-restadapter-at-the-same-time) for an example. You could use the LSAdapter on those specific models.

Comment: I've seen it's possible to do that with App.Store.registerAdapter. I'm trying to use it right now, thank you!