# Using Local storage and REST adapter at the same time?

Tags: rest, ember.js, local-storage, storing-data

I'm pretty new with an Ember so for the start I have a noob question - is it possible to use Local Storage and REST adapter at the same time?

For example, if I want to do a login via API, if login is success the server will return an API key which is used for later communication with a service. Is it possible to store that information locally on the client and to retrieve it when necessary but also, for other models, to use REST adapter?

If this is not a good way to handle such case, which one would you propose and is there any kind of example which would me lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, you need to register a different adapter per model on the Store. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17275098/2488281) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people from #emberjs, I found out that there is a wonderful ember-auth authentication framework for the Ember.js which does what I need.